# Storing Routes and Locations in Graph using SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, graph-databases, sql-graph

I'm very new to Graph database, so please ignore my mistakes. My scenario described in following picture:

[image]

I have different locations connected to each other with a route between them. Then I have many outlets linked to routes.

I created a RDBMS schema like this:

[image]

My data looks like this:

[image: City] [image: linked City] [image: Routes] [image: Outlets]

My goal is to give possible routes and outlets on them between two queried locations.

Recently I heard of Graph database support in SQL Server 2017 and read [this](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/sql-development/sql-server-graph-databases-part-1-introduction/) article, but can't connect with my current problem.

Please help me to create Graph and node tables in SQL Server 2017.

Thanks!

**Update**

Now I create a data model:

[image: Data Model]

and some Node and Edge tables as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mRoute](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)ON [PRIMARY]
)
AS NODE ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mCity](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)ON [PRIMARY]
)
AS NODE ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mOutlet](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [Latitude] [decimal](11, 9) NULL,
    [Longitude] [decimal](11, 9) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)ON [PRIMARY]
)
AS NODE ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[On]
AS EDGE ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LinkedTo]
AS EDGE ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Now I am stuck on `Between` Edge Table, which contains route between two cities.

Comment: Should I move this post to https://dba.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: From the diagram I don't see a need to have LinkedCity and mOutlet database, they are redundant, just for your information!

Comment: Yes @DipenShah, you are right but for not `mOutlet` its `LinkedCity` and `mRoute` which are redundant. Thank for pointing out.